# Getting QCacheGrind to display Call Graph

Tags: anaconda, graphviz, qcachegrind

I'm trying to analyze some code using QCacheGrind. I am using it under Anaconda3 (64-bit) on Windows 10.  To get things going, as a test, I'm profiling a small piece of code from "Advanced Python Programming" by Lanaro, Nguyen, and Kasampalis (page 27).  I've profiled the code using cProfile, and converted the profile output to a call tree using cprof2calltree.  However, when I invoke QCacheGrind on the output of this file, I get this error message in Call Graph tab:

*No graph available because the layouting process failed.

Trying to run the following command did not work:

'dot -Tplain'

Please check that 'dot' is installed (package GraphViz).*

I've checked the list of installed packages, and GraphViz, pydot, and pydotplus are shown as installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Re-installing GraphViz resolved this problem for me on my mac.
I downloaded it from [their website](https://graphviz.org/download/).